# Why does my BLDC motor change behavior at high speed?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

### Background

I've recorded torque vs speed performance of a small sub 50 gram hobby BLDC motor, the [KDE 2304XF-2350](https://www.kdedirect.com/products/kde2304xf-2350).

I power the motor at different fixed voltages to the ESC (electronic commutator) and at different throttle settings for the ESC. The throttle of the ESC essentially steps down the fixed voltage. I measure the "quasi-multiphase" AC electric power entering the motor using a 3-phase wattmeter. I say quasi-multiphase because only a *single* phase of current flows through 2 motor windings at any point in time.

I load the motor using an eddy-current brake: an aluminum disk is connected to the rotor, and the motor/disk are suspended above two electromagnets. Increasing power to the electromagnets induces larger eddy-currents into the spinning disk which generates a larger torque. I measure steady-state torque and speed at different load-currents using an in-line torque cell and a hall sensor.

Here is my data at 8V, 50-100% throttle. Each dotted experimental set has a corresponding solid prediction based a simple DC motor model and KDE's specs.

[image: torque/speed data at 8V, variable throttle]
[image: efficiency with speed]
[image: phase angle with speed]

$$ V = dV_{DC} $$ 
$$ V = IR + E $$
$$ V = \frac{T}{k_t}R + k_t\omega $$
$$ T = \frac{Vk_t - {k_t}^{2}\omega}{R} $$

Where

- \$d\$ is the duty ratio of throttle setting
- \$V_{DC}\$ is fixed voltage entering the ESC
- \$R\$ (182 mΩ) is the *winding-to-winding* resistance of a motor (KDE provides the per-winding resistance of 91 mΩ) because that is the total resistance seen by a voltage applied instantaneously to the motor terminals
- \$k_t\$ (0.0041 Nm/A) is as provided online

### Problem

I simply do not understand why the experimental data diverges from my model at high speeds - specially at low throttle.

I initially though this was some sort of "accidental" field-weakening. The divergence stems from a change in slope, and the slope of a DC motor curve is only a function of \$k_t\$ and \$R\$. At high speed/low current, \$R\$ won't change (low current = low temps), but \$k_t\$ *might* change due to an increase in inductance.

The experimental slope becomes less negative as if the \$k_t\$ has been decreased to achieve more speed, yet the motor still maintains *higher* torque than if \$k_t\$ had remained the same.

For example, at 70% throttle and 10 kRPM, my model predicts ~ 20 mN-m of torque, but the "field-weakened" motor produces 25 mN-m of torque. What gives??

1. **Is this field-weakening of a BLDC?** If so, why doesn't torque suffer?
2. If this is not field-weakening, **what else could cause the torque-speed curve slope to change with speed?**

### Addendum

What also confuses me about this high-speed divergence is that the experimental motor efficiency *improves* with FW.

As I understand FW for PMSMs, some of the stator current (Id?) is spent "fighting" the armature field rather than generating torque (Iq), so you actually lose some efficiency.

However, my motor's experimental efficiency does not drop as precipitously as my model since the motor is producing more speed (relative to the model) at the same torque.

As Neil_UK mentioned, the ESC may be playing some sort trick with the phase angle at the armature. **How can I measure the phase angle at the armature?**

I am already measuring the total phase angle at the motor terminals via my wattmeter (Φ = acos(∑P/∑S) across all 3 phases), but this phase angle includes current lag from speed-increasing inductance and harmonic distortion from noisy switching.

### Hypothesis

Torque doesn't suffer at accidental FW region because the BLDC motor continues to draw *more* power at FW unlike PMSMs that pull "constant" power during FW (ignoring inefficiencies). I will check data now!

Comment: What does 'throttle' mean. I don't mean 'it controls the motor speed', but what does it mean electrically, to the ESC, and how does that enter your model. I think what I'm seeing is 'as the revs rise, I'd expect the torque to fall, but it doesn't fall as much as I'd expect, at lower throttle settings'. If I had a brushed motor running on different battery voltages, that would surprise me greatly. However, with a brushless, there are several opportunities for the ESC to 'do something clever' as the timing changes. Is it doing that? How do you know what 'throttle' is telling it to do?

Comment: How did you derive your model? What assumptions are built-in to it? It seems like the most obvious explanation is that the speed controller does not follow the assumptions built into your model. What does the speed controller actually do in response to different throttle settings? Probably not what you think it does.

Comment: Basically, what is happening is that the motor is running faster than you expect under light load conditions. I think the controller can tell that the motor is not loaded and is using phase advance or something like that to implement field-weakening under those conditions. When the motor is heavily loaded (torque is high) then the experimental data converge with your model.

Comment: I'd suggest that your ESC is a non-sinusoidal drive, so whatever algorithms are being used will be different to any model using sinusoidal drive, They appear to have significantly improved torque in the middle range

Comment: @Neil_UK What do you suggest examining to see if the ESC is being cheeky? I already measure the total phase angle of the motor (phi = acos(∑P/∑S) across all phases), but I'm not sure how much of that phase angle is from high-speed inductance vs low-throttle harmonics. See second plot in post.

Comment: @mkeith I'm trying to find user manuals now for ESC firmware. There is a severe dearth of literature in the hobby world.

Comment: @JackCreasey Are you suggesting that trying to understand this apparent FW in a trapezoidally-driven motor from a PMSM-FW standpoint may be misleading?

Comment: @techSultan Yes. The KDE ESC's certainly appear to be tuned to their motors: https://www.kdedirect.com/collections/uas-multi-rotor-electronics/products/kdexf-uas95hvc ...they have a dynamic PWM frequency and dynamic phase control which would make them harder to model without knowing their management algorithm ….and very costly, probably because of the smarts.

Comment: @JackCreasey That "dynamic frequency" statement is a bit mis-leading. In their [ESC software manual](https://bit.ly/2KvkHE5), there are still 3 distinct PWM frequencies (~ 8, 16, 32 kHz). Granted the phase timing option has much more range per category (15-22 deg for "dynamic", 22-30 for "precision"). I will test again with different timing.

Comment: @techSultan Even with only 3 frequencies, it is still dynamic and the motor capability will vary on each. Certainly not as predictable and modellable as a motor with Hall effect sensors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79766/discussion-between-techsultan-and-jack-creasey).

Comment: What torque cell are you using? Did you calibrate it? How?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I'm using a torque cell rated for 700 mN-m (100 oz-in). The same phenomenon [happened](https://i.imgur.com/ZjNb4wR.png) to even smaller BLDCs tested by the Army using a commercial dynamometer [(report)](https://www.arl.army.mil/arlreports/2013/ARL-TR-6389.pdf). I calibrated it with known weights hung at a known distance. My theoretical and experimental slopes match at low speeds, so I don't think there is measurement error.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're having is related to the form of control you are using. Pretty much every hobby/quadcopter oriented BLDC controller (commonly referred to as 'ESC'), uses sensorless trapezoidal control. This form of control is fundamentally different than the form of control you reference in your question, which is called field oriented control or FOC.

Describing the differences in detail of these control techniques would require an excessively long answer, and I encourage you to research them yourself. However, the test as it currently exists is not properly decoupling the speed/torque characteristic of the motor from that of the driver. The lack of a high resolution encoder also effects the motor performance at low speed. If you want good low speed performance, you need some form of encoder, regardless of the control technique in question.

If you want to properly characterize these motors at a the full speed range you'll realistically need a *sensored* FOC driver.

Comment: I now understand difference between sensored FOC and sensorless 6-step commutation. I was positing that FW is happening "by accident" in the trapezoidal commutation mechanism. I suppose this question is un-answerable without knowing exactly what the control algorithm is under the hood

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple explanation could be that the throttle setting at 50% doesn't mean a stepped down volage by 50%, because if the load is small the current is going back to 0 between pwm pulses so the output voltage is higher than 50%. Look up voltage in buck converter with discontinuous current.
[image]

Comment: I understand how voltage out could increase in discontinuous current mode (DCM), but I don't understand how that would affect the slope of the torque-speed curve. Voltage theoretically only affects the y-intercept of the curve.